# Fields not inserting into my SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I am using visual studio, i have a connection to an SQL server and im trying to update a table in the database.

I am not recieving any errors nor am i updating anything

Below is the code i have used

```
protected void Btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SQL for insert here.
    string MyConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
            ["testconnect"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection();
    myConnection.ConnectionString = MyConnectionString;
    myConnection.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into Don_Test (ID, Test) values ('" + IDTxt.Text + "','" + TESTTxt.Text + "')", myConnection);

    //Call refresh 
    refreshPage();

    myConnection.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is your column types? `ID` sounds like a numeric type based on it's name. And you never execute your query with `ExecuteNonQuery`. Anyway, you should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: You missed to run the query `cmd.executenonquery;`

Comment: numeric and nchar. This is with in the SQL server database table

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are not executing your query, but just opening connection and closing it later.

Add line of code `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` before `refreshPage()`.

Also notice - concatenating query text is very bad idea since it leads to SQL injection attack.

Use [parameterized query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.